# Remove bullepoint from placeholder python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I cant find a way to remove the bulletpoints from the `text_frame`.

```
# Loan Format
loan_no = slide_1.placeholders[1]
loan_no.text = f"Loan {row['Loan_No']}"
loan_no.left = Inches(5)
loan_no.width = Inches(8)
loan_no.height = Inches(0.7)
loan_no.top = Inches(3)
loan_no.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(34,195,187)
loan_no.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.bold = True
loan_no.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(28)
loan_no.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.name = 'Arial (Headings)'
for paragraph in loan_no.text_frame.paragraphs:
    paragraph.alignment = PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT
```

[Text Frame Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXHvX.png)

```
# Clear bullet format for the text frame
loan_no.text_frame.text_frame_format.bullet = False
```